# Program crashes when resuming thread from program but works when resuming from Process Explorer

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

I am learning C and found a little project that interests me. It involves changing the command line arguments to a program when it is started.

The issue I am running into is when I try to resume the thread, the process will just die. If I resume the process from Process Hacker, the process will continue.

This is the code to the program:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winternl.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    BOOL bRet = CreateProcessW(NULL, L"C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\print_my_arguments.exe firstarg secondarg thirdarg", NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    WCHAR szNewCommandLine[] = L"This is the new arguments that will show up.";

    SIZE_T sLen = 0;
    SIZE_T nNewCmdLineLen = wcslen(szNewCommandLine);

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pinfo;
    NtQueryInformationProcess(pi.hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pinfo, sizeof(pinfo), (DWORD*)&sLen);

    // Read the PEB.
    PEB peb;
    ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pinfo.PebBaseAddress, &peb, sizeof(peb), &sLen);

    // Read the length of the Process Parameters buffer.
    DWORD nOriginalProcessParamsLen;
    ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, &((DWORD*)peb.ProcessParameters)[1], &nOriginalProcessParamsLen, sizeof(nOriginalProcessParamsLen), &sLen);

    // Allocate a local buffer to store the contents of our Process Parameters buffer.
    DWORD nNewProcessParamsLen = nOriginalProcessParamsLen + ((nNewCmdLineLen + 1) * 2);
    LPBYTE pNewParamsBuffer = (LPBYTE)malloc(nNewProcessParamsLen);
    RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS* pNewParams = (RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS*)pNewParamsBuffer;

    // Read the contents of the original Process Parameters byffer, into our new local buffer
    ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)peb.ProcessParameters, pNewParamsBuffer, nOriginalProcessParamsLen, &sLen);

    // Allocate a new buffer in the remote process.
    BYTE* pNewParamsAddr = (BYTE*)VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, NULL, nNewProcessParamsLen, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    // Copy the new command line to the end of the new Process Parameters buffer
    wcscpy_s((LPWSTR)&pNewParamsBuffer[nOriginalProcessParamsLen], nNewCmdLineLen + 1, szNewCommandLine);

    // Adjust the buffer size at the beginning of the Process Parameters structure (first two DWORDs)
    ((DWORD*)pNewParamsBuffer)[0] = (DWORD)nNewProcessParamsLen;
    ((DWORD*)pNewParamsBuffer)[1] = (DWORD)nNewProcessParamsLen;

    // Set the command line pointer to the address at the end of the buffer.
    pNewParams->CommandLine.Buffer = pNewParamsAddr + nOriginalProcessParamsLen;
    pNewParams->CommandLine.Length = nNewCmdLineLen * 2;
    pNewParams->CommandLine.MaximumLength = (nNewCmdLineLen * 2) + 2;

    // Loop through all 64-bit values within the buffer. If any of those are found to be within the bounds of
    // the original Process Parameters buffer, adjust them to the equivalent offsets in the new buffer.
    for (DWORD offset = 0; offset < nOriginalProcessParamsLen; offset += sizeof(VOID*)) {
        BYTE* value = *((BYTE*)(&pNewParamsBuffer[offset]));
        if (value >= peb.ProcessParameters && value < (peb.ProcessParameters + nOriginalProcessParamsLen)) {
            *((BYTE*)(&pNewParamsBuffer[offset])) = (value - peb.ProcessParameters) + (BYTE*)pNewParamsAddr;
        }
    }

    // Write the new buffer to the remote process
    WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)pNewParamsAddr, pNewParamsBuffer, nNewProcessParamsLen, &sLen);

    // Write the address of the new buffer to the PEB of the remote process
    WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)(&pinfo.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters), &pNewParamsAddr, sizeof(VOID*), &sLen);

    free(pNewParamsBuffer);

    ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

My `print_my_arguments.exe` program just prints the arguments in a loop. If I comment `ResumeThread(pi.hThread);` then I can resume the process from Process Explorer and a new window will open and start running the argument program and prints them. If the line is still there then the process just dies.

I am not sure what would be wrong. If it works when resuming from Process Explorer and everything prints correctly I am not sure that any of the code is wrong. I am just not sure how I can collect any more information on this process automatically closing.

Thank you

Comment: `pNewParams->CommandLine.Buffer = pNewParamsAddr + nOriginalProcessParamsLen;` looks odd. Isn't `pNewParams->CommandLine.Buffer` a `PWSTR` and `pNewParamsAddr` a `BYTE*`?

Comment: @nahjoh44 You shouldn't send in a string literal to `CreateProcessW`'s second argument. It may actually try to change it - which has undefined behavior. Create a writeable string before calling `CreateProcessW`: `wchar_t cmdline[] = L"..."; CreateProcessW(NULL, cmdline, ...`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nice catch! the ```PWSTR``` was the issue. Now it is working correctly. Feel free to leave answer and I can accept.

Comment: Cool! I think it's better that you write an answer and outline the details and I'll upvote it (if you do a good job at it that is :-) ). (and do change the `CmdLine` argument like I mentioned - it's dangerous to send in a string literal).